# "Too Many Connections" error in Java (MYSQLNonTransientConnectionException)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I want to insert every filename of my local drive into a mysql database.

When I execute this code, it start perfectly.

Code that reads the directory for filenames:

```
public void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "IT MAY TAKE SOMETIME TO LOAD \n PLEASE WAIT FOR CLOSING POPUP!!");
    String s="D:\\";

    Path startingDir = Paths.get(s);        
    String pattern="*";
    Finder finder = new Finder(pattern);
    Files.walkFileTree(startingDir, finder);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"close\n NOW PLEASE CLICK\nSEARCH MY FILE! BUTTON");
```

This is the code to insert the results into the database:

```
public void find(Path file) {

Path name = file.getFileName();
String st = file.toString();
if (name != null && matcher.matches(name)) {
    try {

        Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/login","root","");
        conn.createStatement();
        String query =" INSERT INTO `search`(`path`) VALUES (?)";
        PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(query);
        pst.setString(1,st );
        pst.execute();

        //myst.executeUpdate(query);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

After some time, the scripts stops with this exception

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exception.jdbc4.MYSQLNonTransientConnectionException:
Data source rejected establishment of connection,
message from server:"Too Many connections"
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: You are creating a new connection for each insert statement. You don't need to do that. Create one connection, and use that for all insert statements.

Comment: in addition you can also increase connection limit

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For every insert you create a new connection.  If you keep doing this they build up and eventually you run out of connections to the database.  This limit could be quite small e.g. 20.

Instead you can either

- close the resources you have used. This means closing the `PreparedStatement` and the `Connection`
- or more efficiently, create one Connection and one PrepareStatement *ever* and reuse it.  The saves having to create and clean up resources which can be expensive (unless the driver does this recycling for you)

Answer (score 2):

the easy fix would be to close the connection after you execute the query.

```
pst.close();
conn.close();
```

this should get the job done.
But it'd be better to reuse the connection.